# Using volatile collections and arrays in Java

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, volatile, java-memory-model

Imagine we have

```
volatile int publisher = 0;
volatile List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata");
volatile String[] array = {"Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"};
```

As far as I understand.

Initial values in list and array are published correctly and are visible to all the reading threads.

All values added after the initialization are not safe-published.

Still we can read and publish them safely using

```
//in Thread 1
list.add("Safe City");
array[2] = "Safe city";
publisher = 1;

//in Thread2

if(publisher == 1) {
String city = list.get(3);
city = array[2];
}
```

Am I right?

Comment: Note that the `volatile` keyword applies to the list or array variable itself, not to the contents of the list or array.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  For primitives, `volatile` refers to the primitive value itself.  For objects, the `volatile` keyword refers only to the reference, not the object referred to.  So for `list` and `array`, `volatile` does not have any effect on the contents of the list or array.  `volatile` does not do what what you seem to think it does.

Comment: @JimGarrison in Java 1.5 and newer, volatile guarantees visibility of all the changes made before the assignment to volatile, not just the changes in the vloatile itself. So it can be relevant.

Comment: Note that you cannot add or remove elements from the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList`; you can only set elements without changing the size of the list. This is mostly irrelevant to the memory model issues you're asking about though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct, but...

The `volatile` keyword on the list and array are irrelevant here - the fact that you write a value to the `volatile` `publisher` **after** you write the other values, and read back that value in your `if` condition **before** reading the other values in the second thread guarantees you memory consistency between those threads.

If you remove the `volatile` keyword from the list and array, your code will still be safe.

If you remove the `publisher` variable write/read, then the `add` operation* and array assignment are no longer safe.

And yes, the initial assignment to the variables is also safe.

* *which is actually invalid on that particular list anyway as pointed out by Stuart Marks, but let's assume it's e.g. an ArrayList*

Comment: Thanks CupawnTae, but if I dont have a "publisher" at all - am I correct in these: "Initial values in list and array are published correctly and are visible to all the reading threads. All values added after the initialization are not safe-published" ?

Comment: @Dymytry please see updated answer - I've gone into more detail and it should clarify

Comment: “if you add a write to the volatile variables, even if the value doesn't change, it will become safe again” — this is *wrong*. If the reading thread is not capable of detecting whether the write has happened (which is impossible if the value is the same), then there is no *happens-before* relationship. A write to a `volatile` variable does *not* cause other threads reading that variable to wait for the write to happen. The code in the question does it right as the transition of `publisher` from `0` to `1` is detectable *and* checked by the reading thread. Without that, it would be broken.

Comment: @Holger interesting point. I guess my definition of "safe" was a bit loose here. While the reading thread will be guaranteed a consistent picture at the time they read the variable, there is nothing stopping another thread modifying the collection after that. However, the `publisher` check doesn't stop that occurring either, does it? Writer makes changes, updates `publisher`, reader sees change, reads variable, writer makes more changes, reader reads inconsistent data? Either way, I removed that section, because it was misleading if not completely wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @CupawnTae: Right, any subsequent modification enables the possibility of data races and subsequent writes to the `volatile` variable do not help then. Guarding with a `volatile` variable is a one-time op. That’s why [Stuart Marks said “it's very difficult to extend this code to do anything else”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25577567/2711488).

Answer (score 9):

Looking strictly at what the code is doing, and nothing more, and assessing it only in terms of the memory model, you are correct. The write to the volatile variable `publisher` in thread 1 and the read from the volatile variable in thread 2 establish a *happens-before* relationship, so all previous writes from thread 1 will be visible to subsequent reads from thread 2.

As CupawnTae noted, it's not necessary for the list and the array to be volatile in order for this to hold. Only `publisher` needs to be volatile.

Looking at this from a broader perspective, it's very difficult to extend this code to do anything else. (Set aside the fact that the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` cannot have elements added to it; assume it's an `ArrayList` instead.) Presumably thread 1, or some other thread, will want to continue to add elements to the list. If this happens to cause the `ArrayList` to reallocate its underlying array, this might occur while thread 2 is still reading results from the previous addition. Thus, inconsistent state might be visible to thread 2.

Suppose further that thread 1 wants to do subsequent updates. It will have to set `publisher` to some other value, say 2. Now how do reading threads know what the correct value is to test for? Well, they can read the expected value from some other volatile variable....

It's undoubtedly possible to construct a scheme where thread 1 can write to a list (or array) at will, and thread 2 will never see anything but consistent snapshots, but you have to be exceptionally careful about memory visiblity at every step of the way. At a certain point it's easier just to use locks.

Answer (score 0):

The "publishing" happens between the thread that sets the volatile value and teh thread that gets it.

You need to both

```
publisher = 1;
```

in one thread and

```
int local = publisher;
```

in the other.

Comment: the `if (publisher==1)` that's already in the question is sufficient to satisfy the second constraint

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `synchronized` blocks to provide locking of the data structures that you're trying to read/write to/from?

```
//in Thread 1
synchronized(someLockingMonitor) {
    list.add("Safe City");
    array[2] = "Safe city";
}

//in Thread2
synchronized(someLockingMonitor) {
    String city = list.get(3);
    city = array[2];
}
```

This will however force any thread wishing to access one of the blocks, to wait until any other thread currently executing inside one of these block to leave the block.

If concurrency is important to you, i.e. you really want different threads reading and writing at the same time, have a look at the concurrent collections in `java.util.concurrent`.